# How to find out which the latest version of any dependency we include in Gradle is?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In gradle I do not use dynamic versions because that could lead to indeterminate builds.
So I state my dependencies like so:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
```

However, how do I find out if there is a new version available and what its number is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [gradle-versions-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) to do it. This plugin provides a `dependencyUpdates` task, which

> Displays a report of the project dependencies that are up-to-date, exceed the latest version found, have upgrades, or failed to be resolved.

All you need to do, is to apply, by configuration of build.script dependencies, as:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.11.3'
    // classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5' // uncomment if you're using Gradle 1.x
  }
}
```

And applying the plugin itself, with:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [this site](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp) to search your library latest version.